# org.freedesktop.Hal.Device.Volume.UnknownFailure: mount_udf: /dev/cd0

Tags: freebsd, kde-4

There seems to be a bug with mounting any sort of Volumes in FreeBSD.

The error is as follows:

org.freedesktop.Hal.Device.Volume.UnknownFailure: mount_udf: /dev/cd0

Any help would be appreciated.

I am using KDE4.

Comment: Does this happen with all CD or just with the game CD? Also, what happens if you try to manually mount it? (as toor/root use  mount -t cd9660 /dev/cd0 /mnt` or similar, depending on where you want to mount it. For testing I always seem to use /mnt but modern install also seem to like /media etc etc.

Comment: @Hennes, it appears FreeBSD has trouble mounting UEFI volumes to it's fstab, kinda funny how it wasn't implemented in the 10.1 release, I upgraded to 10.3 STABLE and it fixed my issue.